# Angular - Not hitting http response callback

Tags: angular, http, callback

Hi I am trying to do something with the result of a http request but my callback is never being executed and I can't wrap my head around why..

I've followed the example from [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/) on this [part](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jhades/2375d4f784938d28eaa41f321f8b70fe/raw/1cdaf673d6ed7f627a4833c58fc8829dd7b706f9/07.ts)..

This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as moment from "moment";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/shareReplay';

@Injectable()
export class AuthdataService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

login(email: string, password: string) {

  return this.http
    .post("http://localhost:3000/user/login", {
      email,
      password
    })
    .do(res => this.setSession)
    .shareReplay();
  }

  private setSession(authResult) {
  console.log("Why am I not being hit???")
  const expiresAt = moment().add(authResult.expiresIn,'second');

  localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
  localStorage.setItem("expires_at", JSON.stringify(expiresAt.valueOf()) );
  }  
}
```

---

Updated solution:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {

return this.http
  .post("http://localhost:3000/user/login", {
    email,
    password
  })
  .do(res => this.setSession(res))
  .shareReplay();   
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting the `Observable` sequence you're creating to be "hot", but instead it is "cold". The difference is described [elsewhere on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=reactive+hot+cold) in terms better than I can manage.

In other words, the `.post` doesn't actually do anything *until it is subscribed to*. [Reference](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post).

Invoking `shareReplay` doesn't subscribe to the `Observable`, but only ensures that up to one subscription to the underlying `Observable` will ever be created at once.

So the missing link is probably a call to `.subscribe` on the `Observable` you have created.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer - I'm surprised the Angular University example did not work.

Comment: So it works if I add ".subscribe(this.setSession);" after shareReplay() but I need to do statement to call shareReplay but what should be in the argument of .do() then?

Comment: Since this is a service I can't subcsribe in my components if I add a subscribe here.. I ended up finding a solution which essentially just was a silly mistake ..

Comment: @J.Kirk. I see your updated solution. Sorry I didn't notice that!